# Anti-automorphisms of matrix rings

Tags: matrices, group-theory, ring-theory

I have been looking at automorphisms of matrix rings over arbitrary fields: $M_n(K)$.

With help from here, I have learned that they are all inner automorphisms and hence of the form.

$$ \rho: M \rightarrow PMP^{-1} $$

where $P$ is a non-singular matrix.

Two such automorphisms are the same if $P^{-1}Q$ is in the centre of ring, hence a scalar matrix.  The group of automorphisms is isomorphic to $PGL(n,K)$.

So, now I am adding anti-automorphisms.  The composition of two anti-automorphisms is an automorphism so it seems to be sufficient to find one and how it interacts with the automorphisms.

For matrices, there is an obvious anti-automorphism: the transpose.

$$\tau: M \rightarrow M^T$$

So, now I need to consider how it interacts with the automorphisms.  Let $\rho$ be as above.

$$\rho \tau M = P M^T P^{-1}$$

$$ = (P^T)^T M^T P^{-1}$$

$$ = (M P^T)^T P^{-1}$$

$$ = (M P^T)^T ((P^{-1})^T)^T$$

$$ = ((P^{-1})^T(M P^T))^T $$

$$ = (Q M Q^{-1})^T $$

where $Q = (P^{-1})^T$

$$ = \tau \rho ' M$$

where $\rho '$ is the automorphism associated with $Q$.

Questions

1. Any mistakes above?
2. Suggested further exploration?

This is not homework but brain exercises for an old man,

Comment: Hey. I oo not see any mistake here. For further exploration I guess you could try to determine all the anti-automorphisms. So let $G$ denote the group, under composition, of automorphisms and anti-automorphisms. This definition gives a natural homomorphism $G \rightarrow \{0;1\}$ given by the answer to the question "do you permute products or not?", this should help you determine the anti-automorphisms.

Comment: @nombre Thanks.  I thought that I now had all of the anti-automorphisms: just $\tau$ composed with one of the automorphisms.  Or, do you mean that I should investigate the structure of $G$?  I guess that it will have a similar relationship to the automorphism group as the symmetric group has to the alternating group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is just that.$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}$

I was just proposing that you see the general picture: here you have a group $G$, a morphism $\varepsilon: G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ with a section $s$ given by $s(0) = \id_{M_n(K)}$ and $s(1)= \tau$, so this gives you a structure of semi-direct intern product $G = \Ker(\varepsilon) \rtimes \left\langle \tau \right\rangle \cong GL_n(K) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}_2$. What you wrote lets you see what $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow Aut(GL_n(K))$ is: it sends $1$ to the map $P \mapsto (P^{-1})^{T}$.

Comment: Thanks again.  I need to revise my group theory to continue this game.  I started with ring theory but have been sidetracked to group theory.